# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS wireless suddenly not working more?

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I am using ubuntu 14.04. My wifi was working fine but after sudden it did not worked. I have googled over thousands of fixes and made as like the suggestion. But still I am not getting my wifi in working condition. I have made several restart the system but still its not working.

I have made this script in my terminal

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
chmod +x wireless-info && \
./wireless-info
```

and the output what I got was like [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16082124/)

can someone tell me what exactly the issue is? How to solve this?

Comment: It looks like a hardware issue, or you have disabled the adapter in bios.

Comment: @Pilot6 can you tell me how to solve this issue then?

Comment: If your wireless adapter broken, you can fix it by going to some service or you can replace it yourself. It is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: @Pilot6 is there any method to know that the adapter is safe or not?

Comment: It is not seen in `lspci`. That means it is not there.

Comment: Create a bootCD/bootUSB with Ubuntu 14.04. Boot it. If Wi-Fi still doesn't work, it is a hardware issue.

Comment: Please add logs from /var/log  (including last date when it had work). But it like hw issues or wifi is disabled

Comment: It might be a hardware failure. Does it work with any other Operating Systems on your machine?

Answer (score 5):

If this is a laptop, check for a wireless switch.  You probably have already checked this, but it has caught many people by surprise.  It is usually on the side or front edge of your laptop.  Make sure the switch is turned on for wireless, or try moving it around to see if it brings the wifi card back online.  You may have to reboot before Ubuntu will see it again depending on your install.

Some laptops, like Dell, handle wifi by pressing a function key plus one of the F keys at the top.  Look for one that looks like it has an antenna or wireless signals coming off it.  On most Dells I've worked on it was Function + F2.

On other laptops, wifi can be turned off in the bios when first booting up, but you said wireless stopped suddenly, so this is probably not what happened.  If you are handy inside a laptop and good with a screw driver, a lot of wifi cards can be replaced by just taking off a little panel under the laptop and unplugging the card.  Drop in a new one and get going.  If you don't feel comfortable opening up a laptop, then please take it to a service center or a friend who works on them.

One easy fix, if you cannot get yours working, is to buy a USB wifi adapter.  They can be slower than an internal adapter, but it is much easier to get working, and they are pretty cheap and small now.  Just make sure you research one that works well with Linux.

If you are using a desktop with wifi, then you most likely have a card that blew, and you will need to replace it.

Good luck!

Comment: Also try removing the battery and cord, hitting the power button  a few times, and putting the battery and cord back in.

Answer (score 3):

Its looks to be temporary or permanent hardware failure. There's seems to be no detection of wireless adapter in the log you have attached.

To check the adapters available and network connectivity that is possible in the system try this command.

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

In my laptop i got the output as below.

```
harish@harish-Lenovo-G500s:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for harish:
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8172 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 20:1a:06:a9:99:b0
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:31 memory:d3500000-d353ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 135
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: c4
       serial: 0c:d2:92:c1:8d:d3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:30 memory:d3400000-d3401fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enxaabbccddeeff
       serial: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.132 link=yes multicast=yes
```

This shows the adapter and its details along with the drivers for the adapter.
The adapter name, its type whether wireless or wired and the vendor details is given as,

```
description: Wireless interface
product: Centrino Wireless-N 135
vendor: Intel Corporation
```

The driver name and its version is given in configuration section as below.

```
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.1.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

If the above doesn't give any good output then there might be possible hardware problem. Note, only possiblity, not confirm.

You can also try:

```
ethtool -i wlan0 | grep driver
```

this gives the current loaded driver for your wlan card with output like this:

```
$ ethtool -i wlan0 | grep driver  
driver: brcmsmac
```

If you don't have ethtool you can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install ethtool
```

If this too doesn't work try out Ubuntu live CD by flashing in a USB and give Try Ubuntu.

[image: Try Ubuntu screen in USB Boot]

Try to connect with your wifi there.

If there seems to be no wifi in the notification area then there must be a Adapter failure for sure.